# Gravar log de um campo somente se for insert (trigger SQL Server)

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

tenho uma trigger que dispara quando for insert/update `FOR UPDATE, INSERT`
Eu verifico se o campo foi alterado com:

```
if update (nome)
 --faça algo
```

Como faço pra saber se eu estou inserindo um registro na tabela pra poder gravar um log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeterson, tenho maior conhecimento em Oracle, mas pesquisando um pouco com termos chaves, acredito que ira solucionar seu problema.

> **SQL_STATEMENT**
>
> São as condições e as ações do gatilho. As condições de gatilho especificam critérios adicionais que determinam se os
>   eventos DML, DDL ou de logon fazem com que as ações de gatilho sejam
>   executadas.
>
> Um gatilho é criado para verificar ou alterar dados com base em uma
>   instrução de definição ou modificação de dados. Ele não deve retornar
>   dados ao usuário.
>
> Os gatilhos DML usam as tabelas lógicas (conceituais) `deleted` e
>   `inserted`.
>   <sub>Conforme [Documentação - CREATE TRIGGER
>   (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189799.aspx)</sub>

> A tabela `deleted` armazena cópias das linhas afetadas durante as
>   instruções `DELETE` e `UPDATE`. Durante a execução de uma instrução `DELETE`
>   ou `UPDATE`, as linhas são excluídas da tabela de gatilhos e
>   transferidas para a tabela `deleted`. A tabela `deleted` e a tabela de
>   gatilhos geralmente não têm linhas em comum.
>   <sub>Conforme [Documentação - Usar as tabelas inseridas e excluídas
>   (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms191300.aspx)</sub>

Conforme documentação, para saber se está inserindo um registro, pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted)
  -- update
```

Comment: Opa, deu certinho, verifiquei da seguinte forma: `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED)` . Valeu.